# Calculating a stretchable image with resizableImageWithCapInsets

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimage, image-resizing

I am struggling to work out the parameters for resizableImageWithCapInsets.

I have created a button image shown below, that I will use for Facebook login. I want the Facebook 'f' to be static and the remainder (right side) to stretch as I am sure you can imagine.

[image]

This is my code with the closest output:

```
UIImage *facebookButton = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"FacebookLogin"]
                           resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 36, 18, 18)];
```

Here is the outcome:

[image]

I have tried to follow [this explanation](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/) on the web but I am finding it difficult to understand. If anyone knows the correct resize for this as well as any useful tutorials/guides that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your setting the frame of your button taller than your image. This won't work as the 'f' doesn't look good stretched. The best solution would be to set your button's frame to the same height as the image (36px). But if you need to, set your insets like this:

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 36, 31, 35)
```

This will stretch the blue line just above the 'f' and below the rounded corner, leaving the logo on the bottom left. (The inset order goes top, right, bottom, left.)

Comment: You are right, I can stretch just one image instead of cutting up further thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the link you posted, he is only working with buttons that have no image - the whole button is still stretching, and if he had images on those buttons the result would be what you encountered.

You would need to split your image into the 'icon' and the 'text' parts, kind of like this:
[image]

I'm new to Obj-C, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Ha, I didnt even think to do that - I guess its partly obvious